# Question on TestNG

Tags: java, testing, testng

TestNG doc says create an xml as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
   <test name="Regression1"   >
     <packages>
     <package name="test.sample" />
     </packages>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Where should this file be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you run it.  If you're running from the command line, try this: `java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

If you're using ant, try this. http://testng.org/doc/ant.html

I don't think it matters a lot where you put the file as long as your IDE can find it, you run ant from that directory, etc.  We put all this stuff in a directory called 'build.'

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where this file is kept till you keep providing the accurate path of your testng.xml while executing it. But in case you are designing a framework around it and you need to have have multiple xmls Eg for Sanity, Regression, Performance etc you need to take care of following:

1) Keep all the testng xmls in same directory(Eg: testngXmls). It Keeps the framework's structure clean.

2) As suggested by Tony Ennis you can directly run

> java org.testng.TestNG "pathToTestng file"

or using ant dont forget to add 
`<`xmlfileset file="pathToTestng file"/`>`

3) If using Maven you need to add

> `<`suiteXmlFiles>
>   `<`suiteXmlFile>
>   src/main/resources/testngXmls/testng.xml`<`/suiteXmlFile>
>
> `<`/suiteXmlFiles>

in the maven-surefire-plugin configuration